# Erlang: How to make a loop?

Tags: erlang

How to make a simple loop in Erlang? (For example to loop from 1 to 10.)

Answer (score 10):

Create a recursive structure (this loops 10 times):

```
loop(0) ->
    ok;
loop(Count) ->
    % do something
    loop(Count-1).
```

Or from 1 to 10:

```
do_loop() ->
    loop(1).

loop(10) ->
    ok;
loop(Count) ->
    % do something
    loop(Count+1).
```

You can also use `lists:seq(1, 10)` to get a sequence from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

The code example from Davin Tryon does exactly what you ask: a loop from 1 to 10. But if you run this code, it will simply produce the result ok, without any evidence that it really made a loop: from functional point of view the code could be replaced by:

```
do_loop() -> ok.
```

it has the exact same effect: it produces the result ok. In fact in erlang it is not usual to do such a loop, there are some construct such as list, map, gb_tree, ets... which allow to traverse data in different ways and replace the usual loop you can found in imperative languages.

In Erlang, the most usual loop is the infinite loop which allow to keep a process alive (the while(1) you can find in some C code).

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(ownrecurse).

-export([while/1,while/2, start/0]).

while(L) -> while(L,0).
while([], Acc) -> Acc;

while([_|T], Acc) ->
  io:fwrite("~w~n",[Acc]),
  while(T,Acc+1).

start() ->
  X = lists:seq(1,99),
  while(X).
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions (with the same name), one for if there is no more element in the list and another for your operation. Then you call your function and it calls itself recursive for `N` times.

```
-module(t1).
-export([start/0,myfor/2]).

myfor(0,_) -> 
   []; 
myfor(N,Term) when N > 0 -> 
    io:format("Hello World~n"),
    myfor(N-1,Term).


start() -> 
    io:format("Hello World~n"),
    myfor(5,1).
```

Comment: Please add an explanation

Comment: Explanation added.